Wire fetches data at random times in lwc
Following is my code snippet in lwc:
  async processOpportunities(data, error) {
if (data) {
    console.log('data', data.length);
    this.records = data.map((record) => ({
        ...record,
        StageName: this.getStageInfo(record),
        StageCssClass: this.getStageInfo(record).toLowerCase(),
    }));
    this.defaultSortField = 'Name';
    this.defaultSortDirection = 'asc';
    this.sortRecords(this.defaultSortField, this.defaultSortDirection);
    this.totalRecords = data.length;
    this.pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions[0];
    this.paginationHelper();
}else if (error) {
    console.error('Error while fetching opportunities: ', JSON.stringify(error));
}

this.isLoading = false;
}

@wire(getOpportunities)
async wiredOpportunities({ error, data }) {
    this.isLoading = true; 
    await this.processOpportunities(data, error);
}

and following is my apex function:
public with sharing class OpportunityController {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
   String queryString = 'SELECT ' + 

String.join(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet(), ',') + ' FROM Opportunity';
       List<Opportunity> allOpp = Database.query(queryString);
        return allOpp;
    }` 
}

Now i am new to salesforce, so kindly be patient with me here. I know wire runs twice in lwc. First it checks for any undefined variables and secondly it fetches the data. Now i have 20 records for opportunity in my salesforce org. This wire fetches sometimes fetch 20 records and somtimes fetches 0 records randomly. Now i need to make sure that the second time it fetches 20 records, as i need to display that data in my table. For that i tried making the following changes:
async processOpportunities(data, error) {
if (data && data.length>0) {

But it will create a problem when there are actually 0 records in my opportunities.
Please tell me is this normal for wire to be this unexpected or am i doing something wrong here?
As for why im making a separate function to process records is because that will be used by another function later in my code, so i am making it reusable.
P.s there isn't any error in my console which would guide me through this behaviour.

A question for you: why have you made processOpportunities async when it doesn't do any async execution? You have unnecessarily cluttered your code with await and async from what I can see.

When you say "fetches 0 records randomly", is this for the same contextual user (to exclude sharing being the source of this behaviour difference)?

Yes it is for the same user, this is basically my table, i am fetching opportunity records from apex and displaying them in my table. I can remove the with sharing feature but it won't solve my issue still. I just wanna understand that why is this happening? According to my understanding initlially wire doesn't fetch records only check the undefined values and then when it fires for the second time, it fetches our records. Am i right?
And got your point related to the unnecessary usage of async await. I'll amend that. Thank you
